# Calculating kurtosis from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I am trying to calculate 'kurtosis', as well as other statistics from a numpy array.
Calculating Min, Max, Mean and Standard Deviation are easy as I've just done.

```
import arcpy

x = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(input_Raster)
print 'Min =', x.min()
print 'Max =', x.max() 
print 'Mean =', x.mean()
print 'Standard Deviation =', x.std()
```

Which outputs:

```
Min = 1.87895
Max = 16.8343
Mean = 8.03462
Standard Deviation = 1.52192
```

But this method doesn't work for Kurtosis!
As I've tried

```
print 'Kurtosis =', x.kurtosis()
```

And I get:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'kurtosis'

What would be the simplest code I could use to incorporate into my own to calculate a kurtosis result?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Numpy is restricted to fairly basic array operations, you need to reach out to it's more educated brother, Scipy, to get [more advanced stats functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html).

> [`scipy.stats.kurtosis`*(a, axis=0, fisher=True, bias=True)*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html)
>
> Computes the kurtosis (Fisher or Pearson) of a dataset.

So, `from scipy.stats import kurtosis`, then `kurtosis(x)`.

In general, the methods on Numpy arrays are restricted to only the most basic operations (`max`, `min`, etc.). Slightly more functionality is eked out of Numpy methods (e.g. [`numpy.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)), and more still from Scipy ([`scipy.optimize.[whatever]`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/optimize.html) [`scipy.signal.[whatever]`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/signal.html), [`scipy.stats.[whatever]`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/stats.html))

Comment: Ok so my modified code outputs: 
import arcpy                                                   import scipy
from scipy.stats import kurtosis
input_Raster = arcpy.Raster(filename) 
arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(input_Raster) 
x = arr
scipy.stats.kurtosis(x, axis=0, fisher=True, bias=True)
print 'Kurtosis =', kurtosis(x)

Comment: Kurtosis = [-0.09035063 -0.07390738 -0.14783502 ...,  4.14966822  3.81233072
  2.9377284 ]

Comment: Not sure if that is correct? Thanks very much for the direction - think I need to read up more on kurtosis!

Comment: The shape of the output depends on the shape of the input and axis keyword argument. If you don't care about shape,  you could flatten the array before giving it to kurtosis.